# Django Forms - Proper way to validate user?

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

I'm having a bit of trouble finding an answer on this:
Using Django forms, what's the proper way to provide the current/requesting user?

My form looks like this:

```
class NewProjectForm(forms.Form):

    project_name = forms.CharField(max_length=100)

    def save(self):
        project = Project(name=self.cleaned_data[project_name])
        project.status = 'Working'
        #TODO project.created_by = ???
        project.save() 
        return project
```

Do I need to pass a second argument of user into the save function and I get that from the request or?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you do. However, you could probably save yourself some time by turning your form into a `ModelForm` and then handling the model save in your view:

```
class NewProjectForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Project
        fields = ['name',]
```

And then in your view:

```
if form.is_valid():
    new_project = form.save(commit=False)
    new_project.created_by = request.user
    new_project.save()
```

That way you don't have to worry about passing around your `user` object, and the form itself will take care of setting the other properties for you (for `project.status`, you might try a `default` argument in your field definition).

Comment: Thanks Luke, that works.  Apparently you can also access authentication info through the request metadata as well.

Comment: You can - that's how I'm retrieving the user to attach to the project. I'm a big fan of doing that sort of manipulation in the view rather than the form, but it's really up to you.